# Writing to file with SL4A Python

Tags: android, python, sl4a

Is there an API call for opening, reading and writing to text files on an Android device using SL4A and Python?
If not, what options are available for persistent storage? 
e.g. database, preferences, dropbox, google drive.

Comment: I have worked out how to use preferences, but still interested in other methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was silly to look for a droid command to write files.
The standard Python open, write, read, close commands work fine.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious, and not always precisely true (see subprocess), but generally you use Python as standard for these kinds of things.

Comment: But can you use calls from python's os module to create a file if one doesn't exist? For me the following doesn't work with sl4a:          out_file = os.open("/sdcard/test2.py", os.O_CREAT|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_DIRECT)